# How to crop blank spaces from an image using CSS?

Tags: html, css, image, crop, object-fit

I imported an image to work with on a web project. Turned out that the content of the image is smaller than the image(kind of a blank space all around the content). So, I want to treat this image on my project(using img tag) as though its size was similar to the size of the content itself.

Comment: Add your code snippet

Comment: How automatic do you require this to be? You will need JavaScript if you don’t know the image in advance.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

in your css call the `img` element through the path using classes etc.

and add the following:

```
.insertClassHere img {
    object-fit: cover;
}
```

that should solve your issue.